# Heroku Bot Stops after 24 hours

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I have a small Discord.js reactions bot that gives roles to the members.  It runs fine for 24 hours then it stops... if I refresh the bot with a code it starts working again.

It’s very annoying as I want it to run all the time and not require me to log on every day to manually refresh it.

It is hosted with Heroku if that helps.

Comment: Heroku dynos reboot at least once daily. Chances are you need to store whatever token/code you're using in a database so it can survive the reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ceejayoz.

Comment: Could elaborate slightly please as I don’t know what you mean about the dB... how do I get the bot to use a dB to prevent it from loosing the reactions? 

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos restart one or few times in a day, that's how Heroku's free hosting works. If you lose your reactions use Data base as jonrsharpe said. The easiest to use is MongoDB and there is a lot of tutorials on how to make a reaction role system with it, hope my answer helped!